# How can I prove that this sequence diverges to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to prove that if
$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=\infty$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{n}=\infty$.

I know that since
$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=\infty$, for all positive number M, there exists a natural number $n_0$ such that $a_n>M$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

However, I cannot figure out what to do further.

Comment: You want to conclude that $\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}{n}>M$ for arbitrary $M$. Can you say that $a_1+\ldots+a_n$ is bigger than some simpler expression which you then know is bigger than $M$? (For large enough $n$.)

Comment: Do you mean $a_1+\dots +a_n$>nM>M??

Comment: The sum $(a_1+a_2+\ldots + a_{n_0} + \color{red}{a_{n_0+1} + \ldots + a_n})$ contains $(n-n_0)$ terms that you know are atleast $M$. This allows you to bound $(a_1+a_2+\ldots + a_n)/n$.

Comment: @superdumb Not exactly. How would you conclude that $a_1+\ldots+a_n>nM$? All we know is that $a_n>M$ (for $n$ large enough). For instance we don't know that $a_1>M$. See the question offered as a duplicate.